# Understanding the maximum theorem. Continuity of convex optimization problem with parameterized constraints.

Tags: continuity, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

Given
\begin{align}
s(p)= &\text{arg min}( g( \boldsymbol{x}) ) \\
\text{subject to }&  \boldsymbol{A}(p)  \boldsymbol{x} =  \boldsymbol{b}(p) \\
&c_1 \le x_i \le c_2  , i \in \{1,2,\cdots, n\}
\end{align}.

where 
$  \boldsymbol{A}  \in \mathcal{R} ^{ m \times n}$ is full row rank, with  $m<n $. 
and both $  \boldsymbol{A}(p) $ and $  \boldsymbol{b}(p) $ is continous. Further $g(\boldsymbol{x})$ is continous and strictly convex and the problem is feasible for all $p$.

Does it follow from the [maximum theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem) that s(p) is a continous vector valued function?

---

I believe that I should be able to proove using this theorem (i.e., it seems to me that the conditions for the theorem are satisfied). However I struggle with the notation referenced in the theorem.

For $C(\boldsymbol{x})= \{x:  \boldsymbol{A}(p)  \boldsymbol{x} =  \boldsymbol{b}(p) ,c_1 \le x_i \le c_2  , i \in \{1,2,\cdots, n\} \}$

**1**

Is $C(\boldsymbol{x})$ a compact-valued correspondence such that $C(\boldsymbol{x}) \neq \emptyset$ : Yes since $\boldsymbol{x}$ is always bounded and existence of solution is given by feasibility.
**2**

Is $C(\boldsymbol{x})$ continous: Yes (implicit function theorem?).

**3**

Now all assumptions of the theorem seems to be verified, and since we have strict convexity we must have a unique solutions such that s(p) is a continous vector valued function.

---

So this is may draft, but I feel like I am on shaky grounds. Would be nice if someone could verify.

Comment: Correct. This was a typo. Edited.